# How to use received user data for automatic search/selection of desired content?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing my own web site in order to make movie choosing as convenient as possible. I've already made up a landing page that contains a header where you can find a button which transfers you to a questionnaire form which aim is to collect needed data from user to find and show a list of desired films on the other page. My problem: I have no clue how to use collected data from a user to find desired movies. I guess that I just ought to connect a huge library of films to find appropriate ones, using key words, typed or chosen by a user. However, I don't know what to do as I haven't had such experience yet.

I'm attaching a link to my web site if you would like to investigate: https://rohanian73.github.io/

I would be more than grateful for any explanations or suggestions. Thank you very much for taking the time to read this post. All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting data from the user, you can use any free api to get desired data. **API** is something that can get data from a remote database. 
Here's a free api link, it's called [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/). To use this api you must have a api key which available when you click the header API Key option. 
You can use parameters to query data using this api. Read their documentation for details.

Comment: Ok, I will work with it and study all the necessary information. Thank you very much for sharing such valuable information. May I ask you some questions later, if any?